# Nav element is not affected by display: grid

Tags: html, css

I have a nav with display set to grid inside which I have some ul li elements, but it doesn't work as I anticipated. The li elements are coming as though no grid is applied.

This is the code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.grid-container li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="grid-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="grid-item one"><a href="#">Jenish Potsangbam</a></li>
    <li class="grid-item two"><a href="#">Socials</a></li>
    <li class="grid-item three"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But it works as usual when I apply the `grid-container` class to the ul element instead of nav.

Can anyone explain how they are different and if I wanted to make the nav a display: grid how should I do it?

Comment: Because, when you assign the class to the `nav` it has only one child which is ul and the style is applied to it. But when you are applying it to the `ul` which is the parent of the `lined-items` then the style is being applied to all the children which are the `lined-items`

Comment: I don't see any visual difference between the two scenarios.  But the *structural* difference would be that the `<nav>` as a grid contains only one item, but the `<ul>` as a grid contains three items.

Comment: You should not think how to assign `display: grid` to the `nav`, you should think you have to assign  `display: grid` to the container of the `grid-item`s .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because nav have one child element (ul) so effect of (display:grid) will appear on (ul) only if you need to see li as a grid boxs you should give (ul) class (grid-container) instead of nav to see right effect

remember the effect of display grid appear on child element only so no way to give nav display grid and see effect on li because a li is not a child of nav

see this code

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;

  text-decoration: none;
}

.grid-container li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="grid-container">
    <li class="grid-item one"><a href="#">Jenish Potsangbam</a></li>
    <li class="grid-item two"><a href="#">Socials</a></li>
    <li class="grid-item three"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```